# How can I check if an EJS variable exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I used EJS layout in my Node.js application. Currently I faced a problem when data which is required in the EJS file is not available then it simply generate an error. What I want is to add a condition before using the EJS variable in javascript.

Here is my code in which I use EJS variable inside script tag.

```js
button.addEventListener("click",function()
{
  //here i face an error when sessionID is not available
  stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  sessionId:'<%= sessionId %>'
  })
})
```

here is the code in which I use conditions inside the EJS.

```js
<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
  <%if (data) { %>
    <h2><%- data.name %></h2>
    <h3><%- data.cost %></h3>
    <p><%- sessionId %></p>
    <button id="stripe-button" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Purchase</button>
  <% } %>
  <%if (message) { %>
    <h2><%- message %></h2>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

It also shows an error when it do not receive any message variable.

Error which I received is:

```
message is not defined. sessionID is not defined.
```

Comment: the JS part is inside a .ejs file?

Comment: Yes it is inside the ejs file

Comment: Could you please 'view page source' in your browser and show us the `addEventListener` callback that you end up with?  That should split the problem in half.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your if check is incorrect. You can check `locals.message` or whatever to see if that's exists, then use it.

For your case it will be:

```js
<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
  <%if (locals.data) { %>
    <h2><%- data.name %></h2>
    <h3><%- data.cost %></h3>
    <p><%- sessionId %></p>
    <button id="stripe-button" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Purchase</button>
  <% } %>
  <%if (locals.message) { %>
    <h2><%- message %></h2>
  <% } %>
</div>
```